# How would I "Upload to App Store" to a client's iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have created an app for a client, and instead of uploading to my iTunes connect account, I want to upload it to HIS (my client has a developer account, etc.). After I archive the project in Xcode and press the "Upload to App Store..." button, I am prompted the following message:

**To submit to the iOS App Store, select a Development Team to use for provisioning:**

And then naturally my own name is selected. When I press the "View Accounts..." button, I can see a "+" button to add an Apple ID. I am guessing I would add my client's Apple ID? And then his name will show under Development Teams and I select his name?

Someone please help me understand how to submit to someone else's iTunes connect account. Thank you.

Comment: Typically, you should give the Xcode project to your client, who would then build and submit himself.

Comment: The main problem is that my client does not have a mac (so no Xcode), unless there is another way to submit the app. :S

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to need to get:

1. Your client's private key (.p12 exported from keychain) for his distribution certification, you need it because App Store distribution cert can only have one per bundle identifier. [Click here for instructions.](http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/article/how-to-share-an-apple-certificate-and-its-private-key)
2. Your admin access to his developer program, this enables you the ability to upload archives, you will need sign in this account in XCode. Ask your client to send you an invitation. [Click here for instructions.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/MemberCenter_Recipes/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers/AddingTeamAdminsandMembers.html) Do a `Download All` in Xcode preference after this step.

Then you can can submit again it should be all set.

Answer (score 2):

1. For the developer program your client should invite you as an admin/developer using your main developer id(you don't need a new apple id for the dev. program i.e. you can switch teams).
2. You have to accept the invite
3. Login in the apple developer's website and switch to your client's team  and create the certificates and provisioning profiles you need for the app.
4. Open X-Code preferences and download all the provisioning profiles you need.
5. In your app settings change to the distribution profile of your client(the one you just downloaded in the x-code preferences).
6. Create a new archive of your app in Xcode. Then follow step (7 and 8) or step (9 - added 29/09/2016)
7. When the organizer opens up after the archive is ready, highlight it and press export, then select - "Save for iOS App Store Development". When the export actions are ready save the .ipa file in location of your choice in your computer.
8. After all this is done, open up Application Loader, it is a tool which comes with x-code. Sign in with your apple Id and upload the .ipa file you created earlier.

**---------------- Added 29/09/2016 ----------------**

9. Another way to upload the app is from the organiser press Upload to App Store(blue button on the top right) while the archived build is highlighted. Select your client name from the dropdown in the dialog window press upload and wait until you see green tick

**------------------------****-----------------------------**

10. **All previous steps assume that an entry for the app you are developing is created in your client's iTunes Connect and their apple developer account.**
11. Finally log in to iTunes connect and do all the necessary processes to upload the app in the store.

**Added/Edited on 29/09/2016:** On iTunes Connect - in order to create entry for the app and upload it on their behalf, your client should invite you as an admin with your apple id and you have to accept it. Now you can be present on as many accounts as you are invited so very nice of Apple that they have updated this, saving a lot of time and mess. Change accounts from the dropdown in the top right corner when you log in.

I hope that helps.

Comment: What if your client's just a regular person with no knowledge about iphone / xcode / itunes etc but they just want to sell their app online that you made? What happens then?

Comment: then it is a bit difficult and it depends on how much the client trusts you. One option is you to register the client on iTunes and Apple Dev when client is present and they enter their sensitive info themselves with you instructing them. Another is that you create presentation slides with step by step instructions which we use in our company for such clients and so far we did not have any troubles, all clients were able to do it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a developer account on the developer account you post to iTunes from. They will have to give you permission to access the account. I don't believe you can upload outside of Xcode anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically got it right. You need to add your client's information into your Xcode and then sign and provision the app as your client.

First, you tell Xcode that you want to add a new account:

[image]

Then, you sign in as your client's credentials:

[image]

At this point, you may need to download your client's signing certificates and provisioning profiles if Xcode doesn't do it automatically:

[image]

Then, just select the signing identity of your client and upload your app through either Xcode or Application Loader.

Comment: Thank you for this information. This is probably a silly question... but if I have access to my client's Apple ID, developer account, etc. can I create his signing certificates and provisioning profiles on my own macbook? Or maybe that will create a problem? I am scared to mix anything of his with my own certificates etc.

Comment: @JessThePest That is a problem. You will need all of his certificates. Xcode may download and install them for you, but it is definitely annoying to try to remove them afterwards. I would strongly suggest that your client buy a Mac if he intends to do anything related to iOS again in the future.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I don't download them to my own laptop where I have my own certificates?

Comment: @JessThePest You could, but it might be frustrating trying to manage them.

Comment: What in your opinion would be frustrating about it? I am really new so I am just asking to know what to expect if I choose to go down that route :P

Comment: @JessThePest Having access to another's private keys is generally a bad idea. If you're unsavory, you could sign malicious apps and they would appear to be from your client.

Comment: What if your client's just a regular person with no knowledge about iphone / xcode / itunes etc but they just want to sell their app online that you made? What happens then?